# Dual boot Windows 7 Ultimate + Ubuntu 18.04.2, boot from USB flash disk, can try Ubuntu, but cannot install it

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

Computer information:
My laptop is Lenovo G460
system: win7 ultimate,32 bits
graphic card: NVIDIA GeForce 310M
CPU:Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 M380 @ 2.53GHz
RAM: 2G
BIOS: LENOVO 29CN35WW(V2.12)

I want to install configure a dual-boot system with Windows 7 Ultimate + Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I compressed about 50GB free space in Windows 7, MBR and then I followed the tutorial on Ubuntu's official website to download the ISO and burn it to a USB flash drive.

I successfully entered the "try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu" interface. When I clicked "try Ubuntu", I could connect to WiFi and use Firefox (it seems everything is ok). Then I clicked "install Ubuntu", and after I selected the language and keyboard a "update and other software" window appeared  , I selected "normal installation" and clicked continue. Then it got stuck, and never allowed me to get to the next step (installation type).

I have tried different USB flash drives, but it did not work. I have also tried connecting and disconnecting the network, but it did not work either.

Comment: Not sure this is the issue here, but have you disabled hibernation in Windows 7? [Guide on howtogeek.com](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7564/how-to-manage-hibernate-mode-in-windows-7/). Were you following any particular guide to setup the system?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please open gparted while you are trying Ubuntu. Take a screenshot of gparted window and upload it in imgur.com. Then add the link to the uploaded picture in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much!I'll try and then tell you the result.

Comment: I have disabled hibernation in Win 7,and it does not work.And I was following this guide(https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SOfnvbdWhrs) to install the system.

Comment: I opened gparted when I am trying ubuntu,this is the link  https://imgur.com/a/jQiX25f

Comment: Red icon on sda6 says there is an issue. Sometimes false errors with Windows 10 as some partitions must be unformatted. But if sda6 really has NTFS data, you need to run chkdsk on it from Windows to see if that removes error.

Comment: OK.Thank you!I'll try and tell you the result.

Comment: I had ran chkdsk,and it did not work.I do not know what to do now.Who can help me?